# Getting undesired result "<package>.<class>@55f96302" while working with methods

Tags: java

I am trying to create a basic method to check the whether a person is "Adult" or "Minor". I created two classes viz., Lessons.java (main class) and method.java (method class). When I run the program, I get following result:

*"run:*

*Enter the age: 12*

*lessons.method@55f96302BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)"*

***What is lessons.method@55f96302 ??? And how to resolve it??***

My codes are:

**Lessons.java (main class)**

```
package lessons;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lessons {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    method b = new method();
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter the age: ");
    int age=input.nextInt();

    b.simplemessage(age);
    System.out.print(b);


    }

  }
```

**method.java (method class)**

```
package lessons;
public class method {
public String simplemessage(int age){
if (age >= 18)
return "Adult";
 else
return "Minor";
}
}
```

Any helps??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b.simplemessage(age);
System.out.print(b);
```

Your code calls the `simplemessage` method and does nothing with the return value. Then it prints the return value of `b.toString()`.

It should be

```
System.out.print(b.simplemessage(age));
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I modified my System.out.print code and it worked.

Comment: Hi @VaibhavAgarwal if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check mark.